# Using express I can get my static files to appear in an <img> but they will not open in a new tab

Tags: node.js, express

I am using node and express. I have a simple app that displays images on a react site.  This working.  I wanted the ability to open the images in there own tab.  This causes my site to be rendered when all I wanted was my image.  Any suggestions? Code is below

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

var rootPath = process.cwd();
app.use('/publicImages', express.static(path.join(rootPath, '../../project/images')));

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

If I put this in my index.html file the image renders.

```
<img src="/publicImages/image1.png" alt="" />
```

If I put this in the browser url I get the website rendering

```
http://localhost:3000/publicImages/image1.png
```

Comment: Do you have an environment variable called `PORT` set to 3000? If not, your local web application is listening on port 5000, so an image at `http://localhost:3000` would be unavailable.

Comment: @connor you are 100% correct.  The react ui is on port 3000 but the express server is on 5000.  So navigating to http://localhost:5000/publicImages/image1.png loads up the image.  Any ideas on how to get it to load by opening in a new tab without manually changing the url port ?